# VB.net RGB color sensor "Integer is not valid"

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make VB.net show the data "colors" from my Arduino,
My serial port working great but I have this massage every-time I press connect & weird data show's up

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string " = " to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

Can someone help me in this?
this is my code

```
Public Class Form1
    Private _msg As String
    Dim R As String
    Dim G As String
    Dim B As String

    Dim iR As String
    Dim iG As String
    Dim iB As String

    Private indata As String
    Dim IsConnected As Boolean

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each str As String In IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
            Ports.Items.Add(str)
        Next
        If (Ports.Items.Count > 0) Then
            Ports.SelectedIndex = 0
        End If
        IsConnected = False
        Status.Text = "Disconnected"
        Status.BackColor = Color.MistyRose
        Button1.Enabled = True
        Button2.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If (SerialPort1.IsOpen()) Then

            Try
                SerialPort1.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try


            IsConnected = False
            Status.Text = "Disconnected"
            Status.BackColor = Color.MistyRose
            Button1.Enabled = True
            Button2.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If (SerialPort1.IsOpen = False) Then
            SerialPort1.PortName = Ports.SelectedItem
            SerialPort1.Open()
            IsConnected = True
            Status.Text = "Connected"
            Status.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            Button1.Enabled = False
            Button2.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub



    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        'user chose string
        'read data waiting in the buffer
        Try
            Dim msg As String = SerialPort1.ReadExisting()

            indata = indata + msg
            'Dim where As Integer = InStr(indata, ControlChars.Lf)
            Dim where As Integer = InStr(indata, "R=")
            If (indata.Length > where + 18) Then
                R = indata.Substring(where + 1, 3)
                G = indata.Substring(where + 7, 3)
                B = indata.Substring(where + 13, 3)
                indata = ""
            End If

            'display the data to the user
            _msg = msg
            _msg = _msg.Replace(ControlChars.Cr, "")
            : DisplayData(msg)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


    End Sub

#Region "DisplayData"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Method to display the data to and
    ''' from the port on the screen
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <STAThread()> _
    Private Sub DisplayData(ByVal msg As String)
        DisplayWindow.BeginInvoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf DoDisplay))
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "DoDisplay"
    Private Sub DoDisplay(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        'DisplayWindow.SelectedText = String.Empty
        'DisplayWindow.SelectionFont = New Font(_DisplayWindow.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold)
        'DisplayWindow.SelectionColor = MessageColor(CType(_type, Integer))
        DisplayWindow.AppendText(_msg)
        DisplayWindow.ScrollToCaret()
    End Sub
#End Region

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        RL.Text = R
        GL.Text = G
        BL.Text = B

        iR = CInt(R) * CInt(RM.Text)
        iG = CInt(G) * CInt(GM.Text)
        iB = CInt(B) * CInt(BM.Text)

        RF.Text = iR
        GF.Text = iG
        BF.Text = iB

        Try
            Label6.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(CType(iR, Byte), CType(iG, Byte), CType(iB, Byte))
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs)
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.narzan.weebly.com/p-1049.html")
    End Sub

    Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked_1(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        picOn.Visible = True
        SerialPort1.Open()
        SerialPort1.Write("^")
        SerialPort1.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        picOn.Visible = False
        SerialPort1.Open()
        SerialPort1.Write("<")
        SerialPort1.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub picOn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picOn.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub RL_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RL.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub RM_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RM.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Apparently the problem is neither related to C, nor Arduino. Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am thinking to post my Arduino code too! maybe my problem from there, I don't know yet

Comment: Set breakpoints and step through the code. It helps using them, otherwise debugging issues could be a big pain in the a$$... Thats what they are for...

Comment: I think the first timer tick is causing the code to interpret a value of "=" as an integer in the CInt statement, causing the exception. The "=" value is parsed from the incoming data because the Instr method in the DataReceived routine skips only one character beyond the location of "R=", which is the "=" sign. Try skipping that index one forward.

Comment: What does your Arduino's datastream look like.

Comment: @ David W Yup that's true, I solve that from my Arduino code, by removing R=  G=  B= everything work great now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was from my Arduino code not from VB.net
the solution is to remove "=" from R,G,B

```
void printColour(){
Serial.print("R = ");
Serial.println(int(colourArray[0]));
Serial.print("G = ");
Serial.println(int(colourArray[1]));
Serial.print("B = ");
Serial.println(int(colourArray[2]));
//delay(2000);
}
```

so the code will look like that

```
  void printColour(){
    Serial.print("");
    Serial.println(int(colourArray[0]));
    Serial.print("");
    Serial.println(int(colourArray[1]));
    Serial.print("");
    Serial.println(int(colourArray[2]));
    //delay(2000);
    }
```

Thanks everyone, everything work great now